# EPiServer R2 SP2

Tags: content-management, episerver

I am attempting to install an EPiServer R2 SP2 site on IIS 6.0 and I received the **classfactory not initialised error**. I managed to overcome this by downgrading my web.config to one that is compliant with IIS 6.0

The site loads fine and works as it should all except for edit/admin mode and the default login screen which all seem to have lost the styles and javascript. As a result they are unusable. Any ideas on what has gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Gah! The error lay in not removing one of the name attributes on one of the httpHandlers